# Will Windows Update still work for existing patches for XP systems after next month?

Tags: windows-xp, security, windows-update

As you likely know, official support for Windows XP ended in 2014. I have a question about the exact implications of this.

I know that no new patches were to be created after the April 8 end of life date. However, what I'm unclear about is whether Windows Update still functions to allow XP systems to at least get up-to-date as of the last patch published prior to the April 8 cutoff, or whether Windows Update will not service XP machines at all, even for previously-written patches.

My expectation is that Windows Update will still work to distribute existing patches, because it still allows Windows 2000 to get updates, but I would like to see a link that shows an *official* confirmation of this.

For what it's worth, I updated every system I have direct control over a long time ago. But as someone who frequently is called on to assist fixing PCs for others, I'd like to have a clearer idea what to expect here.

Comment: As long as Windows 7 is supported,Windows XP has to have the capability of downloading updates, because of XP Mode built into Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound According to this MS link, Windows XP mode will no longer be supported within Windows 7: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx

Comment: Windows Update doesn't work for Windows 98 anymore, does it? It seems it was shut down last year.

Comment: Yes; I. Ever said it was supported I said they have to provide the already released updated until windows 7 is not supported

Comment: @grawity I had missed that. I must have been one of the last people to use it, because I had to spin a win98 virtual machine to run an old app about this time last year, as was able at that time to still get it to download the old updates. Or maybe it's because I have a SUS server that's been running for ages that some old things cached yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Will existing updates still be available via Windows Update after April 8, 2014?**
>   Yes, all existing Windows XP updates and fixes will still be available via Windows Update and WSUS

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx